# Is there a concise way to check if an Option is None or if its Some contents are empty?

Tags: rust, option-type

Is there something more concise that the below code?

```rust
let player_list: Option<Vec<Player>>;

// more code here

if player_list.is_none() || player_list.as_ref().unwrap().is_empty() {
  // do something here if player_list is none or empty
}
```

I would like to avoid the `||` part.

Comment: I looked at `std::option` and the most similiar thing I found that might help is `is_some_and`, but I was looking for rather `is_none_or`.

Comment: Is there a meaningful difference between no player list and an empty player list? If not, your code may be simpler if you drop the Option altogether and just use a vector.

Comment: @FredHors I've changed your title to more accurately reflect the question, since it was pretty vague and may have attracted downvotes.

Comment: I wouldn't say it warrants a downvote, but you sure could have invested the research effort of checking through [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html) before asking. I'm also unsure whether this kind of golfing is a worthwhile activity. (Insults absolutely warrant downvotes, but alas, you can't downvote comments.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you probably don't want `player_list` to be consumed. In that case, use:

```
player_list.as_ref().map_or(true, Vec::is_empty)
```

if it's ok to consume `player_list`:

```
player_list.unwrap_or_default().is_empty()
```

Comment: Or: `player_list.as_deref().unwrap_or_default().is_empty()`, without consuming.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Oh wow. I thought `Default` couldn't be `impl`'d for `&…`. [Wrong](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/default/trait.Default.html#impl-Default-for-%26%5BT%5D).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `.map_or` or even `.map_or_else`

```
if player_list.map_or(true, |player| player.is_empty()) {
   // magic
}
```

Of course it is up to you if this is more maintanable.

Comment: That'll consume `player_list`, which is probably undesirable. Also, you have a mismatch between `player`/`player_list`.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make an educated suggestion without looking at the entire context of the code. So, apologies in advance if I am jumping to conclusions.

Having an `Option` of `Vec` is a bit weird. Since `Vec` is already a collection, it can be empty. So, in a way `None` is more or less the same as `Vec()`.

If there is no meaningful difference between `None` and `Vec()`, then maybe converting `player_list` to Vec would be better.

And there are good suggestions in the answers, for example Caesar's answer:

```rust
player_list.unwrap_or_default()
```

If there is a meaningful difference between `None` and `Vec()`. Then maybe having a concrete type that represents these different states would make things easier to understand. In that case you'd probably absorb the different ways the code should behave in that new type.

For example:

```rust
enum GameStatus {
    LobbyNotOpen,
    LobbyOpen(Vec<Player>),
}
```

or

```rust
enum TeamRecruitment {
    NotStarted,
    OpenForRecruitment(Vec<Player>),
}
```